# Execute unknown function name in PHP?

Tags: php

I store a string in a database called "my_function". So to access this string, I'm in scenario where I call:

```
$row->theFunction
```

Furthermore, I am in a class where this function is define, and can ONLY be called like so:

```
$this->my_function($param1, $param2);
```

Now, my problem is, I need to execute my_function, using this. This DOES NOT work:

```
call_user_func( '$this->'.$row->theFunction, $param1, $param2 );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
call_user_func(array($this, $row->theFunction), $param1, $param2);
```

Comment: +1 this is the way I've seen it, except it's function not funciton ;)

Comment: @DigitalPrecision: Oh thanks my fingers betrayed me!  All fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

Aren't PHP variables just great

<sub>`</sarcasm>`</sub>

```
$this->{$row->theFunction}($param1, $param2);
```

You can implement some sanity checking like this

```
if (!method_exists($this, $row->theFunction)) {
    throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Invalid method "%s"', $row->theFunction));
}
$this->{$row->theFunction}($param1, $param2);
```

Comment: They down voted my answer as well, perhaps someone is just being rude.